# Stripping of non-printable characters when formatting as code

Tags: support, code-formatting, editor

I came across a [question by a new user](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50348556/) today. I assume that due to unfamiliarity with the intricacies of the SE editor, they tried to mark a code block using `...` - which didn't quite produce the desired result [[1](https://stackoverflow.com/revisions/50348556/1)].

At this point, I didn't plan to answer, but just to improve the readability of the post by editing it - when I noticed that [the raw post](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/50348556/edit/45499421-10c9-4e76-83a1-5a9279f278dc) contained some non-printable characters, which for me, were a clear indication of the problem with the OP's code:

[image: Screenshot of the end of the OP's raw post]

Unfortunately, after adding indentation and converting the OP's code into a proper code block, these symbols [were gone](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/50348556/edit/2541c5bc-7257-4f8c-b2a2-b682e920d37a), and with them an important hint to the issue exhibited by the output.

**My question**: was there some other way to convert the OP's text into code, while preserving the non-printable characters?

P.S. in case this is somehow related to my system configurations, I was using FF 60.0 on Win10.

Comment: It's worth noting that the problem appears to occur only after saving the post, which means it's a problem with how it's being saved or sent, not with how you're applying the edit. It also doesn't work to use `<pre><code>`.

Comment: Meh, don't worry about it.  Accurate garbage doesn't look that different from formatted garbage.

Comment: @HansPassant while I cannot argue with your statement, I do believe that this is a legitimate concern in similar scenarios (i.e. it's a serious issue if indeed some characters vanish arbitrarily from posts).

Comment: Wouldn't that make it a **a simple typographical error** for which we have a close reason? Honest question, because I can't make much out of the code in the question.

Comment: @ivarni I believe it's a legitimate question and not a typographical error. The problem is that OP did not use a function that converts numbers into characters (i.e. split into digits and add the ASCII value of `0`). In that case, single digits would be printed as their ASCII value, which is a bunch of non-printable characters (appearing in the screenshot as squares). I saw this happen plenty of times, so the immediate suspect was the missing conversion. In my post I meant to say that the OP's problem would be more difficult to pinpoint had it not been for these non-printable characters.

Comment: I see. Fair enough :)

Comment: I had the same problem [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/50122814/13317). The OP was able to paste some text including a Ctrl-Q into his question. I found the question in the close queue and wanted to edit it to make his problem clearer. My attempts to edit it removed the Ctrl-Q.